# Angular $parsers: why is a SPACE disregarded when typed into this INPUT element?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am looking at the directive below in the debugger.  I have a breakpoint set on the line beneath the line that is commented out, at `var transformedInput = text.replace(/\D/g, '');`

When I type a digit into the input, e.g. 1, the debugger stops at the breakpoint as expected. I continue the execution. Then I type a SPACE into the INPUT, but we *don't* fall into the debugger. It's as if the input has not seen the space character. Then we type another digit, e.g. 3, and again we stop at the breakpoint, and the value of `text` variable is "1 3", that is, "1{space}3".

I do not understand this behavior. Can someone explain why typing the space into the input does not cause the fromUser() function to execute?

```
<input int-Only type="text" maxlength="5" ng-model="qty1" />

foo.directive('intOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                // var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/\D/g, '');
                console.log(transformedInput);
                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before angular runs any of the default or custom parsers associated with the ngModelController, it will trim any whitespace by default.

See the baseInputType function in the input directive of the angular source - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js

Try setting the ngTrim attribute to false and your parsers should then be executed.